# form data into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

```js
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Model{
 function __construct(){
  $this->userTbl='login';

 }


public function insert($data=array()){
 if(!array_key_exists("created", $data)){
            $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }

         if(!array_key_exists("modified", $data)){
            $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }

         $insert = $this->db->insert($this->userTbl, $data);


         if($insert){
            return $this->db->insert_id();;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }







}
```

```css
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {
    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user');
    }


     /*
     * User registration
     */

     public function registration(){
      $data=array();
      $userData=array();


if($this->input->post(regisSubmit)){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');

}

$userData=array(
 'name'=>strip_tags($this->input->post('name')), 
 'email'=>strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
 'password'=>strip_tags($this->input->post('password')),
 'gender'=>strip_tags($this->input->post('gender')),
 'phone'=>strip_tags($this->input->post('phone'))

);

if($this->form_validation->run()==true){
 $insert=$this->user->insert($userData);
 if($insert){
   $this->session->set_userdata('success_msg', 'Your registration was successfully. Please login to your account.');

   
  redirect(users/login);

 }
 else{
  $data['error_msg']='Try again';

 }
}


     }
$data['user'] = $userData;
        //load the view
        $this->load->view('users/registration', $data);



    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>User Registration</h2>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" value="<?php echo !empty($user['name'])?$user['name']:''; ?>">
          <?php echo form_error('name','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" value="<?php echo !empty($user['email'])?$user['email']:''; ?>">
          <?php echo form_error('email','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="<?php echo !empty($user['phone'])?$user['phone']:''; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
          <?php echo form_error('password','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="conf_password" placeholder="Confirm password" required="">
          <?php echo form_error('conf_password','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if(!empty($user['gender']) && $user['gender'] == 'Female'){
                $fcheck = 'checked="checked"';
                $mcheck = '';
            }else{
                $mcheck = 'checked="checked"';
                $fcheck = '';
            }
            ?>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php echo $mcheck; ?>>
                Male
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php echo $fcheck; ?>>
                  Female
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="regisSubmit" class="btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p class="footInfo">Already have an account? <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/login">Login here</a></p>              
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in this form I need to insert data into mysql database using codeigniter. but the data is not inserting into the database and also not showing any error. Below is the code for modal, controller and view page. In database.php file, eerything is fine. Here in this, How to debug the code, and what is the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your action field is vacant in the "view". pass the correct URL for registration there

Comment: what part of this has to do with laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You never post anything to your controller. look at this line of your view file.

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Change to :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_URL(); ?>Users/registration" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Define url in routes.php

$route['user/registration'] = 'Users/registration';

- also define your project base_url in config/config.php file
- use

> form action="user/registration"
> method="post">

- instead of

> form action="" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

and view file in

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" value="<?php echo !empty($user['name'])?$user['name']:''; ?>">
          <?php echo form_error('name','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
```

change to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" value="<?php echo isset($user['name']) ? $user['name']:''; ?>">
          <?php echo form_error('name','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
```